# Saving SQL query to xlsx

Tags: python, mysql, excel, xlsx

I've researched this question quite a few times and I can save the query to text which is what I originally did but it's a large query and I'd like to have it organized in excel. However, when I run this script the file grows from 0kb to 8kb but has nothing in it when I open the file? Very strange not sure why my code isn't writing correctly.

```
import pyodbc
import sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook
import datetime


conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=SQL Server32;UID=******;PWD=**********')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM car_search WHERE request_id = 99999999")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
for row in cursor:
    with open('C:\\Book1.xlsx', 'w') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        print (row)
```

I'd like to have the code print out all the rows I've queried for and have them displayed nicely in Excel (2016).

I appreciate all input.

Comment: Well, it's not a *Python* solution, but don't overlook the fact that Excel, itself, is pretty darned proficient at working with SQL databases! You can define a "range" within your spreadsheet that takes its data directly from the SQL source. It can even perform queries. Therefore, "think outside the box." You might not *need* your Python program, at all.

Comment: Indeed, @MikeRobinson. Assuming OP has Excel.exe program, Excel VBA can connect to SQL Server using ODBC directly.

Comment: Interesting, thank you Mike for that I will look into that. My goal is to run an automated test in Python to validate data in SQL whenever a car is requested from a website. So the first test will automate the site for a car request and the second test will go into sql and validate the results and bring them back via a spreadsheet for viewability. This is what I hope to achieve but don't know how possible this is, I'm still new to python and learning as I go.

Comment: Very possibly, you can just perform the test (in Python), then, if successful, arrange some way to invoke Excel such that *it* performs the necessary queries. *(Heh...* "I leave this as an exercise to the reader!") Also: "do they happen to be running a web browser?" "Are they *only* interested in a *(static ...)* tabular display?  Could a `<table>` (generated by Python, with no involvement from Excel ...) do this? "Alternatives abound ..."

Comment: Your code is not using the `openpyxl` module at all. You can't just `print` to a file and expect it to be a valid Excel file. Further, you are re-opening the file for every row, and each time you open it, whatever had been there previously is blown away. There are plenty of examples of how to properly use `openpyxl`, including within its documentation. (Though personally I recommend using `xlsxwriter` instead of `openpyxl`.)

Comment: Also, you don't do anything with `rows` after you've fetched the results into it, so actually, by the time you try to "loop" over the cursor, the cursor is empty. I'm kind of surprised the file gets opened at all.

Comment: And you never do anything with `columns`. But that's probably the least of your problems. Once you figure out how to actually use `openpyxl` (or `xlsxwriter`), it should be clear how to incorporate the column headings.